# ledmac vs. setspace: Don’t change spacing of critical notes

Tags: footnotes, line-spacing, incompatibility, setspace, ledmac

Normaly `setspace` tries to set only the stretch of main text an footnotes are unchanged. In combination with `ledmac` the critical notes are stretched too. Is there a way to *unstretch* the notes like normal footnotes?

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{xltxtra}

\usepackage{setspace}
    \AtBeginDocument{\setstretch{2}}
    % without \AtBeginDocument it leads to an arithmetic overflow
    % don't know why ...

% für die Edition
\usepackage{ledmac}
\newcommand{\BNote}[3][]{%
        \edtext{#2}{\lemma{}\Bfootnote{#3}}%
}
\footparagraph{B}

\begin{document}
\beginnumbering
\setstanzaindents{2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,}
\stanza
inspirat genio. Sed quae depingere vocem &
dextra potest oculisque echo signare videndam? &
\BNote{clarus}{very long text to show the problem\textbf{C}} circa urbes et famae voce lyraeque. &
Illum laetus Hymen plausu iuvenumque choreis &
At tandem \BNote{vergente}{urgente very long text to show the problem\textbf{H}} die festoque peracto &
\BNote{At}{ac very long text to show the problem\textbf{C}} cito colloquio facto dictaque salute &
spondet et oblato sua fata \BNote{paciscitur}{pasciscitur very long text to show  
    very long text to show the problem\textbf{H}} auro.
\&
\endnumbering
\end{document}
```

After lockstep’s answer seem to work fine it stopped working when using `ledpar`in addition to `ledmac`. Here’s the new example.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{ledmac,ledpar}
\newcommand{\BNote}[3][]{%
        \edtext{#2}{\lemma{}\Bfootnote{#3}}%
}
\footparagraph{B}
\usepackage{setspace}
\begin{document}
    \begin{spacing}{2}
        \begin{pages}
            \begin{Leftside}
                \beginnumbering
                \setstanzaindents{2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,}
                \stanza
                inspirat genio. Sed quae depingere vocem &
                dextra potest oculisque echo signare videndam? &
                \BNote{clarus}{very long text to show the problem\textbf{C}}
                    circa urbes et famae voce lyraeque. &
                Illum laetus Hymen plausu iuvenumque choreis &
                At tandem \BNote{vergente}{urgente very long text to
                    show the problem\textbf{H}} die festoque peracto &
                \BNote{At}{ac very long text to show the problem\textbf{C}}
                    cito colloquio facto dictaque salute &
                spondet et oblato sua fata \BNote{paciscitur}{pasciscitur
                    very long text to show  
                    very long text to show the problem\textbf{H}} auro.
                \&
                \endnumbering
            \end{Leftside}
            \begin{Rightside}
                \beginnumbering
                \setstanzaindents{2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,}
                \stanza 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \&
                \endnumbering
            \end{Rightside}
            \Pages
        \end{pages}
    \end{spacing}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To avoid the "arithmetic overflow" error, load `setspace` after `ledmac`. To achieve single-spacing for `ledmac`'s notes, omit `\setstretch{2}` and enclose the document body in a `spacing` environment instead.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{ledmac}
\newcommand{\BNote}[3][]{%
  \edtext{#2}{\lemma{}\Bfootnote{#3}}%
}
\footparagraph{B}

\usepackage{setspace}

\begin{document}
\begin{spacing}{2}
\beginnumbering
\setstanzaindents{2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,}
\stanza
inspirat genio. Sed quae depingere vocem &
dextra potest oculisque echo signare videndam? &
\BNote{clarus}{very long text to show the problem\textbf{C}} circa urbes et famae voce lyraeque. &
Illum laetus Hymen plausu iuvenumque choreis &
At tandem \BNote{vergente}{urgente very long text to show the problem\textbf{H}} die festoque peracto &
\BNote{At}{ac very long text to show the problem\textbf{C}} cito colloquio facto dictaque salute &
spondet et oblato sua fata \BNote{paciscitur}{pasciscitur very long text to show  
    very long text to show the problem\textbf{H}} auro.
\&
\endnumbering
\end{spacing}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Update: unfortunately it doesn’t work with ledpar. Do you have an idea? (I’ve updated my question with a new example)

Comment: @Tobi.  I came across your question by chance.  I had this problem before, too.  See my answer, which I hope works.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this problem once.  You have to dig through ledmac.sty to see what's going on.  However, the fix is pretty easy:

```
%% from ledmac.sty:
%% \newcommand*{\notefontsetup}{\footnotesize}
\renewcommand*{\notefontsetup}{\linespread{1}\selectfont\footnotesize}
```

This worked for me, and worked for your updated example.

Comment: Thanks @jon! The thesis was printed already and I can’t remember how we fixed this but I guess we did fix it. Next time this may be the easier way :-)